# Active Directory / LDAP on .net5 MVC6 application

Tags: active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to find a solution for connecting to **LDAP/Active directory** in order to check for user authentication on a **.Net5 MVC6** web application.
i saw that there is a solution called ADAL but i want to be able to use it without Azure. 
I am looking for a solution that is like the `System.DirectoryServices` (just one that does work with dnxcore50).
has anyone been able to get it to work?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I ended up removing the dnx core 50 and used the 4.51 reference

Answer (score 0):

At least a partial answer to your question comes from [How to use active Directory for ASP.Net 5 (MVC6) Intranet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538724/how-to-use-active-directory-for-asp-net-5-mvc6-intranet-application/34550734#34550734)

Basically use "Windows Authentication" (active directory) along with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: this is not a good solution as it only fits his private case. i'd like my users to be able to set their own domain (for each account lets say) so this solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Identity with LDAP/AD (former Forms based Auth), you should first read

https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

to understand the concept of the storage providers.

Then, there's a sample project that does LDAP Auth with Forms:
https://github.com/jesblit/ASPNET5-FormAuthenticationLDAP (but not for .NET Core)

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

After a lot of research for my own project, there is currently no way of accessing LDAP in .net core (dnxcore50) yet, only in 4.5.1 (dnx451). Except you write your own LDAP implementation...

To achieve Active Directory-Logins with .Net Core 1.0 I implemented AD-Login as explained above but instead of the LDAP-Access (PrincipalContext) I run a small PHP-Script on the same host as the MVC-App that provides a small HTTP POST based Login check using ldap_connect and ldap_bind.