# How to use active Directory for ASP.Net 5 (MVC6) Intranet application

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an intranet application and would like to use the existing organisations Active Directory for user authentication and policy based role authorisation.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I am getting a bit confused (well actually a lot confused).

Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Authentication and Autorization resources under http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/index.html

First start a new ASP.Net Web Application project, Pick the Web Application template then on the right pane press the "Change Authentication" button and pick "Windows Authentication".

You can now use `[Authorize]` on a class or method to check basic authentication vs active directory as of RC2 you can simply use the group names ala     `[Authorize(Roles=@"DOMAIN\GROUP")]`

The now obsolete and cumbersome alternative (still works):

<s>If you look at `User.Claims` you can see the groupsid keys exist for each of the user's groups. Building off that you can do something like `[Authorize(Policy="FOOBAR")]` and define it in your `Startup.ConfigureServices` method via</s>

```
        services.AddAuthorization(
            o => o.AddPolicy(
                "FOOBAR",
                p => p.RequireClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groupsid",
                    "ENTER GROUP SID")
                ));
```

Note that the second param to RequireClaim is a string array to allow for multiple groups.

Also note to figure out group ids via this command line magic `dsquery group -name “ENTER GROUP NAME” | dsget group -sid`

Comment: If the user is not authorised, how would you  redirect to not authorised View()??

Comment: @HariGillala by default it simply throws a http 500, handle that like any other custom error page. Post an actual question for specifics.

Comment: `[Authorize(Roles=@"DOMAIN\GROUP")]` seems to work now with RC2.

Comment: @Jani Thanks for pointing this out! I THINK this was due to a subset of https://github.com/aspnet/Common/issues/85 and it may continue to persist in some circumstances until the cited bug is fully fixed.