# New Authentication-System from ASP.NET Core 1.0 (aka ASP.NET 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm still trying to tinker around with the new ASP.NET Core MVC6 (former vNext). This time I tried to implement my authentication against an Active Directory instead of an Entity-Framework Database.
Since I found so little Documentation, I took the very well done ASP.NET-Template and started to alter it for my needs.
I also use ReSharper to decompile the Parts, since I'm really interested in the Details.

To not go too much into the details, I'm a bit worried I'm doing not the stuff Microsoft intended:
I left the `SignInManager` as it is and removed the `UserManager`, since

```
return await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, false, false);
```

Internally calls the `UserManager`. Now it gets quite tricky: To provide an alternative store to Entity Framework I need to implement

```
IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>
```

Which has around 15 Methods, most of them seem never to get called for my simple Login-Check.
Furthermore, I also need to implement

```
IRoleStore<IdentityRole>
```

Which has another 10 Methods, although I don't even want Role-base Security at the moment!

Furthermore, the Verification of the Password does require a Hash, here is the decompiled Method:

```
protected virtual async Task<PasswordVerificationResult> VerifyPasswordAsync(IUserPasswordStore<TUser> store, TUser user, string password)
{
  string hashedPassword = (string) await store.GetPasswordHashAsync(user, this.CancellationToken);
  return hashedPassword != null ? this.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, password) : PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
}
```

According to other SO-Threads, there is no way to get the Password of the AD, so I can't implement that properly as well.

I think the way to go would be to overwrite the `SignInManager` as well, but this seems to get quite a huge amount of Code, the most not even needed. Also the 2 Store-Interfaces seem to hurt SOLID quite alot, since the interfaces are so big.

Am I dong there something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: [ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) is open source, so I don’t know why you are *decompiling* it to understand it. That being said, I don’t really understand what you are asking.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34538724/216074) if you want to implement Windows authentication using AD accounts.

Comment: @poke: Thanks for your feedback, I'm trying to implement the new Security-System without EF, but with an AD. I also need an Login-Site and an AccountController, not just an AuthorizationPolicy. My question was basically, how to properly implement this, since the  amount of Implementation needed tells me, I'm doing it wrong. Normally I don't ask that broad questions, but I searched quite a while and didn't find any hints.

Comment: What do you need an account controller for? Windows Authentication is implicit; there is no such thing as “enter your password and I’ll check it against the AD” with Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we don't provide an AD version is security.

By implementing one you either now have an AD open to brute force attacks, because you're not disabling accounts (as that could take admin rights, and no-one should run their web app as a domain admin), or you do disable accounts and now, with a few requests I can lock out your users out of AD, which not only affects your web app, but their desktop computers.

Now add on top that in case of a breach I am now authenticated to your AD and, well, that will make attackers happy, but not your network admins.

As an aside, the password check doesn't need hashed passwords, simply authenticate against AD inside VerifyPasswordAsync and return the appropriate result.

My recommendation is either you look at integrated authentication if you are running in an intranet only environment, or Windows Azure AD if you are wanting to run in the cloud. Both of those are markedly more secure than attempting to leverage AD into an HTML forms based scheme.

Comment: Many thanks, seems reasonable. But overwriting this Stores, and leaving the Managers, is your recommended way to go, even the Stores have such a huge amount of Methods?

Comment: Honestly I'd go the manual route and avoid identity altogether. You don't want password resets from the web, or group management, or any of the overhead. Even worse is when you write an identity to a cookie it won't change until the cookie expires. So if you remove someone from a group in AD your web app will still see them as in it.

Comment: Well, I still need the User field, be it just to show a simple "Hello Matthias" and to authrize the Controllers. Seems like I need to find some Middle-Ground here. But you gave me some good hints, many thanks.

Comment: Windows Azure AD will support this. But of course there's a cost involved there I'm afraid.